# How to make multiple y axes zoomable individually

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a bokeh plot with multiple y axes. I want to be able to zoom in one y axis while having the other one's displayed range stay the same. Is this possible in bokeh, and if it is, how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bokeh does not support this, twin axes are always linked to maintain their original relative scale.